# CDF expected value when Y=X^2

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, functions, probability-distributions

So the question asks : 
$$
f_X(t) = \begin{cases}
t^2/3,&\text{if }t\in[-1,2]\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

If $Y= X^2$ what is the range of $Y$? Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ directly using the density of $f_Y(t)$.

So, so far, regarding $Y$ for $t\in[1,4]$ I have done the following.

$$f_Y(t) = P(X^2 \leq y) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y}) = \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} t^2/3 \mathrm{d}t= \sqrt{\frac{y^3}{9}}$$

But the expected value of

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y] =\int_1^4 \sqrt{y^3/9}  \sqrt{y} \mathrm{d}y = \frac{7}{3}$$

Which does not equal the $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ I calculated from using the density of X:

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]= \int_1^2 t^2/3 t^2 \mathrm{d}t = 11/5$$

So is the range of Y or the density of Y calculated incorrectly? Or I am doing the integral of the density in a wrong way?

Comment: If X=0 then what is Y?

Comment: I edited your question and replaced unicode characters for the integral (it should be `\int_a^b`) and the symbol $\leq$ (should be `\leq`). Could you please check everything is fine? I believe you should go through the question once again and make it clearer. Please, take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You were computing the cdf of $Y$, which is a step towards the density. The calculation was wrong, need to treat $y$ between $0$ and $1$ and $y\gt 1$ separately.

Comment: As @AndréNicolas notes, the square root actually has two values, so $P\left(X\leq \sqrt{Y}\right)$ isn't strictly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted in the comments, you appear to be overlooking some aspect of the range of $Y$.  If $Y = X^2$, and $X \in [-1, 2]$, then by inspecting the parabolic segment below—

[image]

—we see that the range of $Y$ is actually $[0, 4]$, and that for $Y \leq 1$, *two* values of $X$ contribute to that value of $Y$, and both must therefore be accounted for.  We must therefore compute the PDF of $Y$ in two segments: $0 \leq Y \leq 1$, and $1 < Y \leq 4$.  For the first segment, we can write, for $y = x^2$,

$$
f_Y(y)\,dy = [f_X(x)+f_X(-x)]\,dx = 2\,f_X(x)\,dx \qquad 0 \leq y \leq 1
$$

Now, $dy = 2x\,dx$, so

$$
f_Y(y)\,2x\,dx = 2\,f_X(x)\,dx \qquad 0 \leq y \leq 1
$$

or

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(x)}{x} = \frac{x}{3}
       = \frac{\sqrt{y}}{3} \qquad 0 \leq y \leq 1
$$

A similar line of reasoning from

$$
f_Y(y)\,dy = f_X(x)\,dx \qquad 1 < y \leq 4
$$

yields

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\sqrt{y}}{6} \qquad 1 < y \leq 4
$$

and then the expected value of $Y$ can be obtained as

\begin{align}
E(Y) & = \int_{y=0}^4 y\,f_Y(y) \, dy \\
     & = \int_{y=0}^1 y\,f_Y(y) \, dy + \int_{y=1}^4 y\,f_Y(y) \, dy \\
     & = \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{\sqrt{y^3}}{3} \, dy
       + \int_{y=1}^4 \frac{\sqrt{y^3}}{6} \, dy \\
     & = \left. \frac{2\sqrt{y^5}}{15} \right]_{y=0}^1
       + \left. \frac{\sqrt{y^5}}{15} \right]_{y=1}^4 \\
     & = \frac{2}{15} + \frac{31}{15} = \frac{11}{5}
\end{align}

---

**ETA.**  One can also compute the PDF $f_Y(y)$ from its CDF (in two parts, as per André Nicolas's comment).  First, for $0 \leq Y \leq 1$,

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & = P(Y \leq y) \\
       & = P(-t \leq X \leq t) \qquad \leftarrow t = \sqrt{y} \\
       & = \int_{x=-t}^t f_X(x) \, dx \\
       & = \left. \frac{x^3}{9} \right]_{x=-t}^t \\
       & = \frac{2t^3}{9} = \frac{2\sqrt{y^3}}{9} \qquad 0 \leq y \leq 1
\end{align}

and next, for $1 < Y \leq 4$,

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & = P(Y \leq y) \\
       & = P(Y \leq 1) + P(1 < Y \leq y) \\
       & = F_Y(1) + P(1 < X < t) \qquad \leftarrow t = \sqrt{y} \\
       & = \frac{2}{9} + \int_{x=1}^t f_X(x) \, dx \\
       & = \frac{2}{9} + \left. \frac{x^3}{9} \right]_{x=1}^t \\
       & = \frac{2}{9} + \frac{t^3}{9} - \frac{1}{9} \\
       & = \frac{1+t^3}{9} = \frac{1+\sqrt{y^3}}{9} \qquad 1 < y \leq 4
\end{align}

and by taking the derivative of this two-piece $F_Y(y)$

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y)
$$

we get the same expressions for $f_Y(y)$ as above.